# using delimiter as column format for impoted txt files

Tags: excel, vba

how can I apply delimiter "^" as columns from imported multiple txt files. Pls Help. ..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim oFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim LoopFolderPath As String
Dim oFileSystem As FileSystemObject
Dim oLoopFolder As Folder
Dim oFilePath As File
Dim oFile As TextStream
Dim RowN As Long
Dim ColN As Long
Dim iAnswer As Integer
On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

Set oFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

RowN = 1
ColN = 1

With oFileDialog
If .Show Then
    ActiveSheet.Columns(ColN).Cells.Clear

    LoopFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    Set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oLoopFolder = oFileSystem.GetFolder(LoopFolderPath)

    For Each oFilePath In oLoopFolder.Files
        Set oFile = oFileSystem.OpenTextFile(oFilePath)

        With oFile

            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                ActiveSheet.Cells(RowN, ColN).Value = .ReadLine

                LoopFolderPath = Space(1)
                RowN = RowN + 1

                Loop

            .Close
        End With
    Next oFilePath
End If
iAnswer = MsgBox("Your Textfiles have been Inputted.", vbInformation)
End With

EXIT_SUB:
Set oFilePath = Nothing
Set oLoopFolder = Nothing
Set oFileSystem = Nothing
Set oFileDialog = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    ' Some code for error handling
    Err.Clear
    GoTo EXIT_SUB

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.RangE("X:X").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("X#"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Other:=True, OtherChar:="^"
```

Of course you will need to replace X:X by the proper column and X# by the proper range.

It took about 30 seconds using the macro recorder to get that code.

Comment: I've tried replacing the the ranges of the X:X and X#. It only sets to a row delimiter rather than a column delimiter. (A:A and A1) I've tried other ranges but gave unsatisfying results :(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by row delimiter and column delimiter

Comment: I want the text to be in 1 column. The text is split into column by the delimiter "^", the code splits text by rows :(. Just the A1 column will be in use.

Comment: What you are saying makes absolutely no sense to me. Post a screenshot of what you have and what you want.

Comment: I want the top to be like the bottom format after importing the txt files... :) https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_eArBbGfxv4Q1pHOS11c2lXdHc/edit?usp=sharing